# DynamoDb map vs string attribute read /update

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a dynamodb table where partition key is userid uniformly distributed. Table store data about User information like(name , email,country, and portal cards the user hold- say user1 has cards1,cards2,cards3 (max 10 category of cards) with detail of cards1 as (gold card,purchased date-yyyy-mm-dd).A user can have Queries on table will be by userid.

1. I need to get how many cards with name and type user1 hold,
2. need to get country of user1
3. Need to get does user1 hold any card of card1 category of gold type
   hold ,which were purchased in current year and whats the country of
   user1.

To achieve this I can design my schema in 2 ways:-

1. Each item has attributes(other than userid partition key) as (Country-string,name string,email string,cards
   map{"card1":{"purchasedate":"yyyy-mm-dd","type":"gold"},"card2":{{"purchasedate":"yyyy-mm-dd","type":"platinum"}}}
2. Make userid as primary key and card category as sort key and keep user info in item with key as userid_all and card info in item with
   key as userid_card1 and attributes of string type as purchasedate
   and type. say  userid1_all : country:Us,email:abc@abc.com
   userid_card1:  purchasedate:yyyy-mm-dd,type:gold

Which approach is better ?

1. Reading data from map attribute is better or from string attribute.
2. Updating attributes with map type(say userid1 for card1 type is upgraded from gold to platinum) is better or string type.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Though DynamoDB supports Document data types (Map, List etc), the query API is not very robust. In your design approach 1, if you convert the data into DynamoDB item, you will actually end up with complex object (i.e. card1 value is an object with two attributes purchasedate and type) for cards attribute. The third query pattern has the requirement to filter by purchasedate and type which DynamoDB API doesn't support as it is inside another object of MAP data type rather than some scalar attribute inside MAP.

**Simple object of MAP:-**

```
{"purchasedate":"yyyy-mm-dd","type":"gold"}
```

**Complex object of MAP:-**

```
{"card1":{"purchasedate":"yyyy-mm-dd","type":"gold"},"card2":{"purchasedate":"yyyy-mm-dd","type":"platinum"}}
```

So, the **design approach 2** is better. As long as you have scalar attributes (i.e. String, Number, Boolean), you can query the table by different combinations of attributes in **`FilterExpression`**.

Comment: so If I go with approach2 , I will have to make 2 calls to dynamodb for third query pattern - getting country and card1 detail ?  and for query pattern1 multiple items will be fetched with same partition key user1- will that be costlier than having 1 item returned in approach1 ?